# Delete zero string in array using matlab

Tags: matlab

I having a problem in deleting zero string, so i have a code that generates a 
string array:

```
a =['29.74473'  '       0'
'42.56682'  '75.38116'
'52.79034'  '       0'
'61.77224'  '16.23368'
'70.04864'  '       0'
' 77.9089'  '40.75286'
'93.09803'  '16.60231'
'100.7078'  '       0'
'100.7078'  '       0']
```

i want to delete rows containing '0' string, so i used this code:

```
       a(strcmp(a(:,2),'       0'),:) = [];
```

but it didn't delete those '0' in the array, so how i will do that? thanks.

Comment: You just edited the code to your question so that there is no problem anymore... You should not do that!

Comment: So, it works with the code that you have listed in the code, right? Or, do you have cells with varying lengths of whitespaces around the `0` string, in which case it might fail.

Comment: Please to not edit your question to show the answer. When you do this the question is useless to future viewers. You can always answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

By using `[]` instead of `{}`, you are building a `9-by-16` char array instead of a `9-by-2` cell array containing strings. That's why `strcmp` returns no perfect match of the string.

What you want is to build `a` by:

```
a = {...
'29.74473'  '       0'
'42.56682'  '75.38116'
'52.79034'  '       0'
'61.77224'  '16.23368'
'70.04864'  '       0'
' 77.9089'  '40.75286'
'93.09803'  '16.60231'
'100.7078'  '       0'
'100.7078'  '       0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtrim`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) to remove the whitespaces around the `0` string seen in the sample input which were causing the issue of *non-detection* with your original approach. So you can use `strtrim` alongwith `strcmp` to have the desired output like so -

```
a_out = a(~any(strcmp(strtrim(a),'0'),2),:)
```

Or

```
a_out = a(all(~strcmp(strtrim(a),'0'),2),:)
```

Or with `regexprep`, you can replace `strtrim(a)` with `regexprep(a,'[^\w'']','')`.

Sample run -

```
a = 
    '29.74473'    '       0'
    '42.56682'    '75.38116'
    '52.79034'    '       0'
    '61.77224'    '16.23368'
    '70.04864'    '       0'
    ' 77.9089'    '40.75286'
    '93.09803'    '16.60231'
    '100.7078'    '       0'
    '100.7078'    '       0'
a_out = 
    '42.56682'    '75.38116'
    '61.77224'    '16.23368'
    ' 77.9089'    '40.75286'
    '93.09803'    '16.60231'
```

Comment: Hm. This only works for cell-arrays containing strings, in which case the OP's approach of `a(strcmp(a(:,2),'       0'),:) = [];` also works. (The question was edited from `[` to `{`, so currently the question doesn't make any sense anymore, as it works...)

Comment: @knedlsepp Ah! I didn't notice that!  But, OP's original approach won't work with varying lengths of whitespaces around `0` string. Posted query comment on that, let's see!